# Magento - adminhtml grid edit action doesn't work

Tags: magento, gridview

I don't know much about grids in magento, but I neet to create one. Grid works, but when I click on a row there's an error: `Fatal error: Class '(Namespace)_Logger_Block_Adminhtml_Logger_Edit' not found in \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php on line 491`
Which file could be responsible of this error? Catalog structure:

```
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Edit/Tab/Form.php
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Edit/Form.php
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Edit/Tabs.php
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Edit.php
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Grid.php
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Grid.php
Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Loggerbackend.php
Logger/Helper/Data.php
Logger/Model/Mysql4/Logger/Collection.php
Logger/Model/Mysql4/Logger.php
Logger/Model/Logger.php
Logger/controllers/Adminhtml/LoggerbackendController.php
Logger/etc/config.xml
Logger/sql/logger_setup/...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error was so stupid :/ Class name wasn't correct.

```
Path: Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Edit.php
Name: Logger_Block_Adminhtml_Loggerbackend_Edit
```

Thanks for all help :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe magento is looking for a Class named: '`(Namespace)_Logger_Block_Adminhtml_Logger_Edit`' so your missing the following file: 
`/(namespace)/Logger/Block/Adminhtml/Logger/Edit.php`

Comment: But there is such a file in my module.